# Child process using boost::process::child reading some characters from STDIN

Tags: c++, boost, stdin, boost-process

Main process is spawning a child process as follows:

```
bp = boost::process
bp::child(cmd.c_str(), bp::std_out > bp::null, bp::std_err > bp::null, boost::this_process::environment());
```

where cmd = `"setsid <some other executable>"`

Now, while working on the main process, we are observing that some of the keystrokes (characters) are being printed in the log file of the other executable and missing from the main process.

We were not using setsid earlier, but now we can see that the process-group of the main process and child process are different. We also checked if there's a direct call to input from STDIN, but that's not the case either. We are using Boost 1.79.

Comment: Can you make a self-contained reproducer, preferrably mentioning the OS/platform you run it in

Comment: I'll try to add a reproducible code here in some time.

OS: CentOS Linux 7
Arch: x86-64
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.76.1.e17.x86_64